# Save the waffles! Bringing back custom 404 pages to Stack Exchange

Tags: script, images, typescript

> As per Aaron's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368048/786798), the change is **temporarily** reverted due to the backlash, so the userscript is not necessary for now. To compensate for the loss in usefulness, I decided to add per-site user overrides (since 0.3.0) and allow it to work on the current 404 pages (since 0.4.0).

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Meta Stack Overflow 404 page]

Custom user overrides:

[image: Meta Stack Overflow 404 page with user override]

<sub>The image is "The Black Beast of Aaaaaargghh" from the ["Monty Python and the Holy Grail"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python_and_the_Holy_Grail) film, 1975</sub>

### About

The userscript brings back custom 404 pages to the Stack Exchange network replacing the lifeless corporate warning icon with community-specific images while preserving the updated layout. Currently supported communities (some 404 pages were never indexed by archive.org, so if you know of the missing 404 images, please let me know):

| Community | Image |
| --- | --- |
| Stack Overflow | [image: Stack Overflow 404] |
| Meta Stack Overflow | [image: Meta Stack Overflow 404] |
| Ask Ubuntu | [image: Ask Ubuntu 404] |
| Super User | [image: Super User 404] |
| English Language Learners | [image: English Language Learners 404] |
| Code Review | [image: Code Review 404] |
| Unix & Linux | [image: UNIX 404] |
| Sci-Fi | [image: Sci-Fi 404] |
| Math | [image: Math 404] |
| Server Fault | [image: Server Fault 404] |
| Ask Different | [image: Apple 404] |
| Cross Validated | [image: Cross Validated 404] |
| Arqade | [image: Arqade 404] |
| Mi Yodeya | [image: Mi Yodeya 404] |
| Home Improvement | [image: Home Improvement 404] |
| Cooking | [image: Cooking 404] |
| Crypto | [image: Crypto 404] |
| Webmasters | [image: Webmasters 404] |
| Chemistry | [image: Chemistry 404] |
| Raspberry Pi | [image: Raspberry Pi 404] |
| Emacs | [image: Emacs 404] |
| Database Administrators | [image: 404] |
| Graphic Design | [image: 404] |
| Android Enthusiasts | [image: 404] |
| Movies & TV | [image: 404] |
| Software Recommendations | [image: 404] |
| Academia | [image: 404] |

#### Change Log

v0.3.0 introduces per-site user overrides and a configuration modal accessed by clicking on a "404" button added to the main site menu:

[image: site menu with config button added]

The modal allows you to change the image source for each of the sites with custom 404 pages (ability to add sites to the list coming soon) - it will be loaded instead of the default image:

[image: configuration modal feature]

Since v0.8.0, there is a small icon next to each of the configuration labels - clicking on one takes you to the corresponding 404 page:

[image: config item with icon link]

Since v1.1.1, there the configuration modal supports custom header text as well:

[image: config item with custom header input]

Day-to-day changes:

| Version | Updates |
| --- | --- |
| 0.6.0 | options menu item is added for logged out users (or those without an account on a community) too |
| 0.6.1 | Added explicit support for the [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) userscript manager |
| 0.7.0 | Made modal draggable and made configuration modal load even on unsupported sites |
| 0.8.0 | Added quick links to 404 pages of each of the supported site |
| 0.9.0 | Added true cross-site configuration for Tampermonkey users |
| 0.10.0 | Added DBA, Android Enthusiasts and Graphic Design defaults |
| 1.0.0 | Deferred image replacement till "load" event; first major version |
| 1.1.1 | Added "Page not found" user overrides |
| 1.2.0 | Added Software Recs, Academia, and Movies & TV defaults |
| 2.0.0 | Switched to userscript manager-agnostic [storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@userscripters/storage); fixed config item broken by recent UI updates |

#### License

The script is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

[Install](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-404/raw/master/dist/modern/index.user.js) | [Minified](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-404/raw/master/dist/modern/index.min.user.js)

The script *doesn't need* a userscript manager to work (but includes necessary headers).

Note that overrides are available **cross-site** only in userscript managers due to the nature of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

#### Platform

Version number means "last tested on":

| Chrome | Opera | Firefox | Edge | IE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 92.0.4515.107 | ✔ 77.0.4054.203 | ✔ 89.0 | ✔ 92.0.902.55 | no |

Userscript managers:

| Greasemonkey | Tampermonkey | Violentmonkey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 4.11 | ✔ 31 | ? |

### Contact

Author: [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)

Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Please, submit bug reports [on the source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-404/issues).

Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-404/blob/master/src/index.ts) written in TypeScript.

Contributions are welcome, you can always [submit a PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-404/pulls).

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

### All Missing 404.

| Site | Image | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Wordpress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/abc) |  |  |
| [Music](https://music.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Acadmeia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [World Building](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] |  |
| [emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/abc) | [image] | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |

As far as I know, the 404s that have a black background, are transparent, but I am not sure.

Comment: I've tried each one, and it appears Stack Exchange added them back for these sites, so they work without the help of a userscript.

Comment: @Anonymous yup, SE *temporarily* added those back after the backlash (see notice on the question). Thus to preserve usefulness til the day when they remove them again, the script now allows user customizations (using local storage, so be careful with private windows)

Comment: @OlegValter How do you customize them?

Comment: @Anonymous the script adds a menu item to the main menu (see the question for a screenshot of how it looks like or look for "404") which opens the customization modal on click :)

Comment: @OlegValter That button doesn't do anything when I click it (or show anything in the console).  This seems like a bug...

Comment: @Anonymous done, seems to be an issue with GM restrictions - bumped to 0.6.1

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Changing the `.js` prefix to `.user.js` would allow [Greasemonkey](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page) to auto-detect that it is a userscript and install it by simply clicking opening the file.